# limit point set and closed condition

Tags: real-analysis

Here is the question

> *Prove that the set of limit points of a set is closed.*

I'm not even understand the question fully. 
Is question meaning 
$\{E= {N_\epsilon(p) }\}$? if you said $p$ is the limit point?

How do you approach this question?

Comment: Are we in a metric space here or a general topological space?

Comment: general topological space

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space; denote its set of limit points by $A'$.  Choose any $x$ in  the closure of $A'$.  Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$.  Then $U - \{x\}$ meets $A'$.

Now pick $y\in U$ with $y\not=x$ so $y\in A'$. Then $U$ is a neigbhorhood of $y$ and $y\in A'$ so $U$ must meet $A$ somewhere other than $y$.  Thus every deleted neighborhood of $x$ meets $A$.  Hence $x\in A'$.

Answer (score 0):

You should prove the following: If $x_n$, $n\in\mathbb N$, are limit points of $X$ and $x_n\to x$, then $x\in X$.

Comment: I don't think this is true in general topological spaces.

Comment: That is if $x$ is in the closure, then there must be a sequence converging to $x$. This is not true.